# Button is not getting focussed

Tags: android, button

I cannot focus the button once it is clicked.. Below is my code...

```
   Button lt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    lt.setFocusable(true);
    lt.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    lt.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

This is my selector file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:color="@android:color/black"
    android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/black"
    android:state_focused="true" />
   <item android:color="@android:color/black"
    android:state_hovered="true" />
 <item android:color="@android:color/black"
    android:state_selected="true" 
   />
 <item android:color="@android:color/black"
```

And this is my xml button:

```
   <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.00"

            android:textColor="#cd3207"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
            android:src="@drawable/button_selector" 
            android:focusable="true"
            android:background="@drawable/selctor" />
    android:state_hovered="true" />
```

Comment: are sure about your button xml structure?

Comment: button.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `lt.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);` to your code or try [requestFocus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#requestfocus-element) tag in xml and let me know the result please so I can help you more.

Comment: No its not working..RequestFocus you can use it only at one button ..I have four buttons

Answer (score 0):

You need to use selectors for this...

put an image first for initial button and later for a clicked one